# Gigabyte fast boot option doesn't work anymore after adding new HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, bios

Before I added a new hdd to my system I had fast boot option enabled in bios and when I would boot the motherboard would skip the bios screen and boot quite fast. Now, after adding a 2tb seagate hdd the motherboard no longer skips the bios screen and takes significantly longer time to boot.

Why does the fast boot option not work anymore after adding a new hdd? I understand that adding a new sata device might slow the boot time slightly, but shouldn't the fast boot option work as intended and skip the bios screen at boot?

**Specs:**
MB: Gigabyte Gaming K3 (updated to latest bios)
CPU: i5 6600k
OS SSD: Samsung 250gb evo
HDD: WD 1TB Blue
New HDD: Seagate Barracuda 2TB

Comment: Does it boot normally if you remove the HDD again? Just an idea, does the new HDD show in the menu of bootable devices in the BIOS?

Comment: Just tested this, after removing the new hdd, the pc boots faster and with no bios screen, what's interesting is I then went into bios settings and saw that the fast boot is disabled. What is going on with my bios? Did I potentially corrupt it? I read somewhere that you have to disable the fast boot option before adding any new devices to your system, but I didn't...

Comment: the fast boot option just skips some tests etc., so no harm should done. So you can replicate the error by adding hard disc again, right? Did you try to enable fast boot again? What about the bootable devices?

Comment: @Albin I tried everything, after reconnecting the new hdd I even turned on the ultra fast boot option, doesn't seem to make a difference, the bios screen is still present. I checked the boot order, everything looks fine, ssd first then hdds. Maybe the fast boot option no longer works after adding a couple hdds?

Comment: I don't think just the number of HDDs should make a difference, if it does it will say so in you're boards manual. Did you check there yet?

Comment: what about your bootloader sequences? is this hard earlier than your main hard?

Comment: @HosseinVatani The Seagate is last in the list.

Comment: I guessed this is a hardware issue, because, at boot, the system would try to know all devices. maybe a port which you connected your Seagate is damage.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following way to resolve the issue:

1.Delete the other hard disks in the startup item, only leave the original HDD(WD 1TB Blue).

2.Then we enable "fast boot".

3.We set "SATA SUPPORT" as "Last Boot HDD Only".

We now have three hard drives, so the boot self-test is slow. After we set it like this, it prevents the computer from detecting the other two hard drives, it will only detect its boot disk.

The BIOS screen will not be skipped, it will only pass by, or stop for a few seconds.

This is [the Gigabyte BIOS manual](http://download.gigabyte.cn/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z270-gaming-k3_e.pdf) I search, we can view if we need.

Comment: By delete you mean disable the Seagate from Hard Drive BBS priorities?

Comment: I mean disable the Seagate from boot priorities.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Delete the other hard disks in the startup item, only leave the original HDD(WD 1TB Blue).
>
> 2.Then we enable "fast boot".
>
> 3.We set "SATA SUPPORT" as "Last Boot HDD Only".

And here I am December 2021 looking to solve this issue that's plagued me for years.
I tried this suggestion and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1094733)